# Complex JSON, How to get value?

Tags: python, json

COMPLEX JSON GET VALUE in Python? I`m trying to extract the value 9 but i dont get it.
How to extract the value of **9**? I tried this:

```
data = json.loads(string)
data['fiednf']['0']['idk'])
```

but doesn`t work.

```
{
"ABC":"ABC",
"EDF":{
"name":"name",
"EDF":true
},
"GHJ":"",
"FG":"geometryType",
"GH":{
"RT":wkid,
"ED":latestWkid
},
"editval":[
{
"nome":"name",
"tipo":"type",
"alias":"alias",
"sqlType":"sqlType",
"domain":null,
"defaultValue":null
}
],
"fiednf":[
{
"numbers":{
"idk":9
}
}
]
}
```

Comment: If you format indents as they are supposed to be, you'll probably see it for yourself. Also `fiednf` defined twice, that's probably a mistake.

Comment: Yes sorry i edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
print(data["fiednf"][0]["numbers"]["idk"])  # -> 9
```

`data["fiednf"]` is a **list** and their contents are generally referenced via integer indices. In this case you want the first (and only) element in the list, so an index of `[0]` must be used.

I often find it helpful to pretty-print the data to see its structure better. In this case you can do with:

```
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

The result in this case looked something like this:

```
{
    "ABC": "ABC",
    "EDF": {
        "name": "name",
        "EDF": true
    },
    "GHJ": "",
    "FG": "geometryType",
    "GH": {
        "RT": "wkid",
        "ED": "latestWkid"
    },
    "editval": [
        {
            "nome": "name",
            "tipo": "type",
            "alias": "alias",
            "sqlType": "sqlType",
            "domain": null,
            "defaultValue": null
        }
    ],
    "fiednf": [
        {
            "numbers": {
                "idk": 9
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am. What's in your question isn't valid JSON. In order to get it to load so I could print it out, I had to put quotes around `wkid` and `latestWkid`.

Answer (score 2):

To access 9 you can do this:

```py
print(a['fiednf'][0]['numbers']['idk'])

>>> 9
```

You only use string indexes for dictionaries and int indexes for lists, also the key `fiednf` is duplicated.